# Change some words translation in vendor

Tags: magento2, localisation

I've installed spanish translation from composer package (mageplaza).
this package, create a file "es_ES.csv" in vendor/mageplaza/mage...spanis/es_ES.csv

I would like to change some words... Now, If I would like to change it, I must go to edit es_ES.csv file in vendor folder... but I think, that it's not correct. So... what it's the correct way in order to change some words that exists in vendor.... es_ES.csv file, but I want to change the translation?

Magento2.3.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace the text to the desired error message in this file

> app/design/frontend/Vendor_Theme/Theme_name/i18n/en_US.csv

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you install language package successfully.After you install add your language package in your theme below path.

```
app/design/frontend/Your_Vendorname/Your_Themename/i18n/es_ES.csv
```

**`THANKS.`**